# Retrieve an exp-resso store value from a Store field within an EE relationship

Tags: expresso-store, relationships

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but with the following code I am having issues in pulling the 'price' information. see tags towards the end of the code: £{price}

At the moment all the correct images and

#### {related_products:product_manufacturer}

{related_products:short_description} are showing correctly. However the price pulls out the same price for each item, when it should show the correct price for each item, not the same price!

The 'Price' tag is pulled from exp-resso store. And I think this is where the issue is. Could any one help?

Thank you kindly in advance.

The code I'm using below:

```
<section class="related"> <!-- start section -->
    <div class="container"> <!-- start .wrap -->
        <h3 class="upper">You may also like</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                {exp:channel:entries channel="store" status="open|featured" limit="3"}
                    {related_products}
                        {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}"}
                            <li class="col-md-4 product"> <!-- start .span4 -->
                                <a href="{path="store/detail"}/{related_products:url_title}">
                                    {exp:channel_images:images entry_id="{related_products:entry_id}" field="product_image_one"}
                                        <img src="{image:url}" title="{related_products:title}" alt="{related_products:title}" />
                                    {/exp:channel_images:images} 
                                    <div class="overlay"> <!-- start overlay -->
                                        <h3>{related_products:product_manufacturer}</h3>
                                        <h4>{related_products:short_description}</h4>
                                        <p class="price">&pound;{price}</p>
                                    </div>
                        {/exp:store:product}
                                </a>
                            </li>
                    {/related_products}
                {/exp:channel:entries}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using entry_id in the store tag and not the related entry_id. Try this:

{exp:store:product entry_id="{related_products:entry_id}"}